# Trampolines in C++ Metaprogramming

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, trampolines

I am reading a book on metaprogramming and there is secession on Trampolines:

```
struct generic_t
{
    void* obj;
    void(*del)(void*);
};
template <typename T> // outer template parameter
generic_t copy_to_generic(const T& value)
{
    struct local_cast // local class
    {
        static void destroy(void* p) // void*-based interface
        {
            delete static_cast<T*>(p); // static type knowledge
        }
    };
    generic_t p;
    p.obj = new T(value); // information loss: copy T* to void*
    p.del = &local_cast::destroy;
    return p;
}
```

I totally understand how it works but I don't know what is the application of it! and where do you usually use this technique? dose anyone know about it? thanks :)

Comment: Type erasure has many uses. One major and reusable example is [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/any.html). Trampolines are just a stepping stone in achieving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use it in many places in my programs. One thing I like with this method is that you can hold a list of unrelated types. For example, I've seen a lot of code that looked like that:

```
struct Abstract { virtual ~Abstract() = default; };

template<typename P>
struct AbstractHandler : Abstract {
    virtual void handle(P) = 0;
};

template<typename P, typename H>
struct Handler : AbstractHandler<P>, private H {
    void handle(P p) override {
        H::handle(p);
    }
};

struct Test1 {};

struct Test1Handler {
    void handle(Test1) {}
};

struct Test2 {};

struct Test2Handler {
    void handle(Test2) {}
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Abstract>> handlers;

    handlers.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Handler<Test1, Test1Handler>>());
    handlers.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Handler<Test2, Test2Handler>>());

    // some code later....

    dynamic_cast<AbstractHandler<Test1>*>(handlers[0].get())->handle(Test1{});
    dynamic_cast<AbstractHandler<Test2>*>(handlers[1].get())->handle(Test2{});
}
```

Dynamic casts add unnecessary overhead to the program. Instead, you could use type easure just like the one you've made to avoid this overhead.

Plus, there is no reason for `Abstract` to even exist. It's an interface that expose no useful function. The real need here is to hold a list of unrelated interfaces.

---

Let's say we ajust type easure to allow `copy_to_generic` to cast the instance to a parent class.

```
template <typename Parent, typename T>
generic_t to_generic(T&& value) // forward is better.
{
    struct local_cast
    {
        static void destroy(void* p)
        {
            // we cast to the parent first, and then to the real type.
            delete static_cast<std::decay_t<T>*>(static_cast<Parent*>(p));
        }
    };

    generic_t p;

    p.obj = static_cast<Parent*>(new std::decay_t<T>(std::forward<T>(value)));
    p.del = &local_cast::destroy;

    return p;
}
```

Look at this code with the type easure:

```
// No useless interface

template<typename P>
struct AbstractHandler {
   // No virtual destructor needed, generic_t already has a virtual destructor via `del`
    virtual void handle(P) = 0;
};

template<typename P, typename H>
struct Handler : private H {
    void handle(P p) override {
        H::handle(p);
    }
};

struct Test1 {};

struct Test1Handler {
    void handle(Test1) {}
};

struct Test2 {};

struct Test2Handler {
    void handle(Test2) {}
};

int main() {
    std::vector<generic_t> handlers;

    handlers.emplace_back(
        to_generic<AbstractHandler<Test1>>(Handler<Test1, Test1Handler>{})
    );


    handlers.emplace_back(
        to_generic<AbstractHandler<Test2>>(Handler<Test2, Test2Handler>{})
    );

    // some code later....

    static_cast<AbstractHandler<Test1>*>(handlers[0].obj)->handle(Test1{});
    static_cast<AbstractHandler<Test2>*>(handlers[1].obj)->handle(Test2{});
}
```

No empty interface and no dynamic casts anymore! This code does the same thing as the other one, but faster.